# Change shell script file access permissions (chmod) from itself

Tags: 12.04, bash

Is it possible to change shell (Bash) script file access permissions (chmod) from itself ?

for example if i have file named myScript.sh , can write into the file :

`chmod 777 myScript.sh` ?

and run it (`sudo ./myScript.sh`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, so let's start a simple test:

```
% cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env bash
chmod 777 foo

% chmod 555 foo

% ls -laog foo
-r-xr-xr-x 1 34 Nov  4 12:58 foo

% ./foo

% ls -laog foo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 34 Nov  4 12:58 foo
```